# resources for learning CSS... when you know the rest of the stack

Tags: css

#### Duplicate

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084/can-you-recommend-a-good-css-online-resource-or-book
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199486/what-is-the-best-book-on-css

I've got a gaping hole in my quest to be a more complete web programmer, and it's CSS. I do lots of front-end / middle-tier / back-end Java work, including a fair amount of Javascript, so I'm not a newbie at building websites. Unfortunately, I've always had the luxury of CSS/JS-specialists coming in to polish off the crap HTML I write (`<pre>` FTW), and so I never really learned how to make those tables pixel-perfect.

Yes, I know there's a billion and one resources on Google, but was hoping there might be some hidden gems, be it books, blogs, sites that you might recommend to learn CSS basics, best practices, browser quirks, in a straightforward manner for someone with a programming background.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084/can-you-recommend-a-good-css-online-resource-or-book and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199486/what-is-the-best-book-on-css

Answer (score 1):

I like the [sitepoint css reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) materials.  We use this PDF of the [Ultimate CSS Reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/cssref1/) around my office

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [O'Reilly CSS: the Definitive Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/CSS-Definitive-Guide-Eric-Meyer/dp/0596527330/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1222340657&sr=1-1) by Eric Meyer, arguably THE CSS guru.

You may find the [answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book/132621#132621) useful too

Answer (score 1):

Can't go far wrong with CSS tutorial on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) to get started. Also includes a try-it-yourself facility for having a quick play.

Also, found the one that helped me out with the float thing: [tiztag](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php). There's more good stuff on there too.

Answer (score 0):

The book 'The Ultimate CSS Reference' by Sitepoint's guru's, Tommy Olsson and Paul O'Brien, answered all of my questions. I highly recommend this reference.  Once you understand the different options for Position and Float, and a few other rules, it really clarifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/) writing both interesting and useful. He has links to collections of CSS resources as well as his own writings and musings.

Answer (score 0):

For advanced articles about CSS, you might want to check out http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/